# Java Jackson XML Parsing

Tags: java, xml, jackson, десериализация

Есть XML вида:

```xml
<list>
    <testcase classname="ClassName1" name="TestCaseName1" time="0.020">
        <failure message="Failure Message" type="Type of failure">Extended failure message</failure>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="ClassName2" name="TestCaseName2" time="0.030">
        <error message="Error Message" type="Type of error">Extended error message</error>
    </testcase>
</list>
```

Мне нужно собрать это все в класс Java используя Jackson
Я пробую:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TestCase {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String name;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String classname;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "failure")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private String failureExtendedMessage;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "error")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private String errorExtendedMessage;
}
```

Как мне получить `Failure Message`, `Error Message`?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте атрибут

```
 @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Нужно для `failure` и `error` создать классы, подобные `testCase`.
А в классе `testCase` поля сделать экземплярами этих классов.